# cleanup after execution of all tests ( spock framework )

Tags: java, testing, junit, automated-tests, spock

i'm looking for a solution that allow me to handle the setup and the cleanup of my test environment at the launch and the end of my test framework execution.
The setup is not a problem but the cleanup imply to know when the test framework has finished to work or the index of the current test in execution queue.
Has someone a solution to implement this?

Comment: Maven has `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` for this. In gradle you'd have to define your own tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension` to achieve this, as Spock extensions have callbacks for both BEFORE all specs start, and AFTER all specs end.

```
public interface IGlobalExtension {
  void start();
  void visitSpec(SpecInfo spec);
  void stop();
}
```

So, implement `stop()` in your case to do whatever you need to do.

Spock finds extensions via Java's `ServiceLoader`, so make sure to add a `META-INF/services` file (pre-Java9) or declare it in your `module-info.java` file (post Java9), as explained here: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/extensions.html#_writing_custom_extensions

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an abstract class that all your specs extend:

```
class AbstractSpec extends Specification
```

then inside `AbstractSpec` find out the classes that are going to be run(for example if you're using spring framework):

```
private static final synchronized TEST_CLASSES = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false).with {
    addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(AbstractSpec.class))
    findCandidateComponents("com/example/test").findAll { it.beanClassName != AbstractSpec.class.canonicalName }
            .collect { Class.forName(it.beanClassName) }
}
```

then inside `AbstractSpec` do the actual clean up after all classes are run:

```
def synchronized cleanupSpec() {
    TEST_CLASSES.remove(getClass())
    if (TEST_CLASSES.isEmpty()) {
        // clean up here
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that if you run a subset of tests or classes in your IDE; you might have all the test classes in the classpath so `TEST_CLASSES` won't be emptied so the clean up won't execute.